# How return position of pointer in function of searching substrings in strings?

Tags: c++

Help please how to finish function.
I got exersize for develop function for searching substring in string and return first position of enter.
That is code what i made:

```
int strstr(const char *str, const char *pattern) {
const char *st = str; // assign adress of string to pointer
const char *pa = pattern; //assign adress of pattern what we must find in string to pointer
while (*st){ // starting sort out string
    ++st;
    if( *st == *pa){ //when first symbol of pattern equal to symbol of string starting the loop
        int i = 0; //counter of iteration for possibility to return first enter of substring

        for(i;*st == *pa;i++){ //that loop sort out every next symbol of string and pattern for equality
            ++st;
            ++pa;
        } //loop finish when pattern or string was ended, or any next symbol was not equal

        if(*pa == 0){ //if patter was ended return position of first enter
            return st-i; //there not compiling((
        }

        pa-i; //reset pattern
        st-i; //reset string
    }
}
return -1; //return -1, if substring was not find
}
```

For hard luck that code not compiling... Error is invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’
What type must be variable i for that? And check my logic please)

Answer (score 0):

```
return st-i; //there not compiling((
```

You are returning a pointer to a constant char, where your function requires to return an integer. My best guess is you need to change it into:

```
return *(st-i)
```

Use the * to dereference the pointer into the const char object, which is interchangeable with int

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function is currentlu defined to return an `int`.

**If you desire to return an `int`,** such as the relative position from the beginning of your string, then you have to return a difference between pointers

```
return (st-i)-str;    // st-i = begin of the pattern found,  - str for the relative position
```

**If you desire to return a pointer,** then your function signature shall be changed and you should return `nullptr` instead of `-1` when you didn't fin the patter.

Several other minor issues:

- incrementing `st` before starting comparison risk to miss the pattern if the string starts with it.
- `pa-i` and `st-i` are without effect: it's just expressions, no change is stored.  Maybe you wanted to write `pa-=i` ?

Comment: Very very big thanks for advices) On local all working. Trying to pass test)

Comment: Passed only 5 tests from 42( Somewhere fail in logic(

Comment: I notice also that `for(i;*st == *pa;i++)` doesn't work if pattern is found at the end of the string: you continue after the end of the string.  Rewrite it `for(i;*st == *pa && *st;i++)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. At least it looks simpler.:)

```
#include <iostream>

int strstr( const char *str, const char *pattern )
{
    bool found = false;
    const char *p = str;

    for ( ; *p && !found; ++p )
    {
        size_t i = 0;
        while ( p[i] == pattern[i] && pattern[i] != '\0' ) ++i;
        found = pattern[i] == '\0';
    }

    return found ? --p - str : -1;
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << ::strstr( "Hello evsign", "evsign" ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
6
```

As for your code then even the first statement in the loop is wrong

```
while (*st){ // starting sort out string
    ++st;
```

Why is st increased?

Also this loop

```
for(i;*st == *pa;i++){
```

shall be written as

```
for( ;*st == *pa && *pa; i++){
```

Comment: Your variant was working fine) Thanks) But my with bugs( st++ - i trying to iscrease adress of string for changing adress and pass all over all array)